# Access Ubuntu share from Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016

Tags: networking, windows, samba, shared-folders, smb

I've got problems with accessing shares of my Ubuntu machine from my Windows 10 PC.

I already tried to edit smb.conf:

---

min protocol = SMB2

max protocol = SMB2

client min protocol = SMB2

client max protocol = SMB2

---

Access still not working.

I tried to enable SMBv1 on my Windows 10 PC: Access still not working

The same trouble I got on Windows Server 2016.

**I can access without problems from Windows 7 PCs, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2008 R2.**

Which settings do I have to change on my Windows 10/Server 2016 machines?

Comment: hi there! welcome to askubuntu! :) have you looked into ubuntu's own folder sharing option? https://websiteforstudents.com/easily-share-ubuntu-17-10-public-folder-with-windows-10/

Comment: Yes, that's how I shared the folder on Ubuntu. Works for older Windows systems

I guess on newer Windows systems there is a new authentication setting or something else

Comment: hold on, you wern't password protecting the folder? you shoud do that.

Comment: Ubuntu machines are just running in Hyper V and network access is limited to the hardware PC. don't worry ;)

Comment: no but the reason I use the password, isn't for that (I have the same closed sircuit, nobody can acess), it's because with the password it actually connects, without it it doesn't work.

Comment: still not working with password. Can't imagine that this is the problem because older OS can access properly

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the output of the following commands from your Ubuntu machine: "testparm -s" and "net usershare info --long"

Comment: I found the solution: In Windows 10 insecure guest logons are not allowed by default

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser

...but allowing this causes lower security

Comment: @tatsu how do you share your folders? My way is just to click right on a folder and select 'Local Network Share'

But I can't specify a user. When I try to map a network drive from Windows with different credentials it fails

Comment: I share ubuntu-side. I'll look at what I set up on my desktop when I get home tonight.

Comment: I share on ubuntu-side too. Please let me know what you set up

Thanks!